# Flask route decorator type hinting

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a simple Flask application with which I've added a decorator to ensure a specific header is present on each request.

```py
import functools
from http import HTTPStatus

import flask
from flask.typing import ResponseReturnType

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


# What type hints should be added to this?
def requires_header(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def check_headers(*args, **kwargs):
        if not flask.request.headers.get("X-Foo"):
            flask.abort(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return check_headers


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
@requires_header
def root() -> ResponseReturnType:
    return flask.jsonify(success=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask.run(host=0.0.0.0, port=3000)
```

What type hints should I add to the `requires_header` decorator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running Mypy with the `--strict` setting, the following is the best way to type this *at present*. This is very similar to [@Samwise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69472480/13990016), but note that the `TypeVar` is bound to `Callable[..., Any]` rather than a bare `Callable` (Mypy `--strict` will not allow any unparameterised generics, even as arguments to a `TypeVar`). We also have to help Mypy out when it comes to the return type of `requires_header` — it can't verify that we're *actually* returning the type we say we *should* be returning, so we help Mypy out with [a call to `typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast).

```
import functools
from http import HTTPS
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, cast, Any 

import flask

C = TypeVar('C', bound=Callable[..., Any])

def requires_header(func: C) -> C:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def check_headers(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        if not flask.request.headers.get("X-Foo"):
            flask.abort(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return cast(C, check_headers)
```

The above solution obviously has its flaws, however, mainly the number of times we've had to use `Any`, which should generally be used as little as possible. Python 3.10 has [introduced a new feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) specifically to help with typing decorators, `ParamSpec`. Mypy unfortunately does not yet support this feature, but when it does, we will be able to type your decorator like this instead:

```
import functools
from http import HTTPS
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, cast, ParamSpec 

import flask

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def requires_header(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, R]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def check_headers(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        if not flask.request.headers.get("X-Foo"):
            flask.abort(HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND)

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return cast(Callable[P, R], check_headers)
```

It may be that using `ParamSpec` will also do away with the need for the `cast` in the last line of the decorator — but it's difficult to tell, since Mypy doesn't yet support the feature, so it's sadly not yet usable!

Comment: oh dang, the amount of annoying copy+paste `ParamSpec` would have saved me when typing decorators that transform the return value...

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator takes a callable argument (any kind), and returns a callable of the exact same type.  Hence:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

_C = TypeVar("_C", bound=Callable[..., Any])

def requires_header(func: _C) -> _C:
    ...
```

Note that this is different from doing something like:

```
def requires_header(func: Callable) -> Callable:
    ...
```

since this does not guarantee that the decorated function has the same type as the original function (it effectively becomes two *different* `Callable[..., Any]` types, which wrecks type checking for anything that calls that function).  Using a `TypeVar` allows the original type to pass through the decorator unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using `mypy` with the `--strict` flag and after adding your suggesting I'm receiving the following errors;
Missing type parameters for generic type "t.Callable", Function is missing a type annotation for one or more arguments, Returning Any from function declared to return "_C".

Comment: You need to explicitly give the `Callable[..., Any]` type in the bound then -- updated answer!